# How to get selenium to move the slider in google extensions settings

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make an Instagram bot and it somewhat works but I want it to be able to post pictures, the extension I'm using blocks the page after a few seconds of it being loaded. I found a thread somewhere and someone said if you go into incognito mode it fixes this problem.  The problem is I don't know how to make the move the slider with XPath.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from info import pw
from info import email
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('mhh.crx.crx')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extension")

class InstaBot:
    def __init__(self, username, pw):
        self.username = username
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/path stuff/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_options)
        sleep(1)
        self.driver.get("chrome://extensions/?id=jkcghkeldalkgfhgenmcblejihijdpha")
        sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'crToggle')]")\
           .click()
        #sleep(2)
        self.driver.get("chrome-extension://odlpjhnipdekfkdkadoecooboghijleh/app/index.html")
        sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Log in')]")\
        .click()


my_bot = InstaBot('tonka_r_us', pw)
```

pictures:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4XDu.jpg

Comment: First of all you can not treat google extension elements like normal web page elements, as they wont be identified by XPaths. Also to work with slider in normal webpage, you can just click as they are toggle buttons.

Comment: so how would I get the path for it to be able to click?

Answer (score 0):

To open your Chrome webdriver in incognito mode, best way is to use Options.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('..\drivers\chromedriver',options=options)
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

Comment: The question was to _...move the slider in google extensions settings..._ but not open `--incognito`.

Comment: could i do options.add_argument("--incognito", ""--disable-extension"")                            or would i need to do two separate lines

Comment: you need to add as many arguments as you want line below:
options.add_argument("--incognito") 
options.add_argument("--disable-extension").